# How to create list view/grid view/recycler view with retrofit API in jetpack compose

Tags: android, listview, retrofit, android-jetpack-compose

I have created Kotlin Code for parsing APIs with retrofit in list view/grid view/recycler view, I wanted to know how can I do the same using jetpack compose? I have used retrofit to parse GET API responses using different ViewGroups. View Binding is used to interact with the views on this screen.

**Code**

```
 import android.annotation.SuppressLint
                import android.app.AlertDialog
                import android.app.ProgressDialog
                import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException
                import android.content.DialogInterface
                import android.content.Intent
                import android.content.res.Configuration
                import android.os.Bundle
                import android.util.Log
                import android.view.*
                import android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo
                import android.widget.*
                import androidx.activity.viewModels
                import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
                import androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil
                import okhttp3.ResponseBody
                import org.json.JSONArray
                import org.json.JSONException
                import org.json.JSONObject
                import retrofit.Retrofit2
                import retrofit2.Call
                import retrofit2.Callback
                import retrofit2.Response
                import retrofit2.Retrofit
                import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory
                import supports.*
                import viewmodel.SIViewModel
                import java.io.IOException
                import java.net.SocketTimeoutException
                import java.util.*
                
                
                class TestIndex : AppCompatActivity() {
                    var adapter: Adapter1? = null
                    var dialog: AlertDialog? = null
                    var builder: AlertDialog.Builder? = null
                    private val viewModel: SIViewModel? by viewModels()
                    var test_arr = ArrayList<TestModel>()
                    var binding: TestGridBinding? = null
               
                
                    @SuppressLint("CommitPrefEdits", "ClickableViewAccessibility", "SetTextI18n")
                    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
                        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
                        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.test_grid)
                        setSupportActionBar(binding?.view?.toolbarr)
                        supportActionBar!!.elevation = 0f
                
                        viewModel
                
                
                       
                        adapter = Adapter1(this@TestIndex, R.layout.row, test_arr)
                
                
                
        //binding ViewModel retrofit API with activity, here ID1 and ID2 coming from the previous screen.
                        viewModel!!.getList(this@TestIndex , ID1!!, ID2!!)
        
                        binding?.gvTest?.adapter = adapter
                
        
                        binding?.swipeRefreshLayout?.setOnRefreshListener {
                            binding?.swipeRefreshLayout?.isRefreshing = true
                 
                                if (ID1 != null && ID2 != null) {
        
        // getting same server response on swipe refresh widget
                                    getdata(ID1!!, ID2!!)
                                } else {
                                    builder = AlertDialog.Builder(MyApplication.instance)
                                    builder!!.setCancelable(false)
                                    builder!!.setTitle("Alert")
                                    builder!!.setNegativeButton("Cancel") { dialog: DialogInterface, which: Int ->
                                        dialog.dismiss()
                                        finish()
                                    }
                                    builder!!.setPositiveButton("OK") { dialog: DialogInterface, which: Int -> dialog.dismiss() }
                                    dialog = builder!!.create()
                                    dialog?.show()
                                }
                
                        }
                
                
                
                        subscribeObservers()
                    }
                
//this is checked on the dev portal but I don't know I could I use it //dynamically with adapters and ArrayList.
                    @Composable
        fun LazyRowItemsDemo() {
            LazyRow {
                items((1..title_arr.size).toList()) {
                    Text(text = "Item $it")
                }
            }
        }
                
                
                    private fun getdata(id1: String, id2: String) {
                
                        val mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog(this@TestIndex)
                        mProgressDialog.isIndeterminate = true
                        mProgressDialog.setMessage(Keys.KEY_pre_msg)
                        if (!this.isFinishing) {
                            mProgressDialog.show()
                        }
                        val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                            .baseUrl(Keys.testURL)
                            .client(OkHttpClient().build())
                            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                            .build()
                        val retrofitInterface = retrofit.create(
                            RetrofitInterface::class.java
                        )
                        val call = retrofitInterface.getTestdata(id1, id2)
                
                        call!!.enqueue(object : Callback<ResponseBody?> {
                            override fun onResponse(call: Call<ResponseBody?>, response: Response<ResponseBody?>) {
                                var remoteResponse: String? = null
                                if (response.code() == 200) {
                                    try {
                                        assert(response.body() != null)
                                        remoteResponse = response.body()!!.string()
                                    } catch (e: Exception) {
                                        e.printStackTrace()
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    try {
                                        if (response.errorBody() != null) {
                                            remoteResponse = response.errorBody()!!.string()
                                        }
                                    } catch (e: IOException) {
                                        e.printStackTrace()
                                    }
                                }
                                if (remoteResponse != null) {
            
            //getting response fields and parsing list view or grid view/recycler view in different screens
            
                                        adapter =
                                            Adapter1(this@TestIndex, R.layout.row, test_arr)
                                        binding!!.gvTest.adapter = adapter
                                        adapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged()
                
                                }
                            }
                
                            override fun onFailure(call: Call<ResponseBody?>, t: Throwable) {
                                Log.d(Keys.KEY_TAG, "onFailure: " + t.localizedMessage)
                            }
                        })
                        if (mProgressDialog.isShowing) mProgressDialog.dismiss()
                    }
                
                
        //subscribed the Observers here from view model
                    private fun subscribeObservers() {
                        viewModel!!.lifting.observe(this, { TestModel: List<TestModel>? ->
                            adapter!!.updateTests(TestModel)
                            binding!!.swipeRefreshLayout.isRefreshing = false
                    }
                
                }
```

Kindly let me know how can I do the same using jetpack compose for listview, grid view, recycler view. Thanks.

Comment: check out about [lazy lists in Compose](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/lists#lazy)

Comment: I have seen some demos of lazy lists in Compose but couldn't update them according to my needs.

Comment: Show what compose code have you tried, and what is not working as you expect. check out about compose [view models](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state#viewmodel-state) too, you can perform your data processing there

Comment: Sir, please check i have updated the LazyRowItemsDemo function that I want to update list view/grid view/recycler view with arraylist, I am not sure how can I update it from API call and sync with adapters dynamically.

Answer (score 2):

It's more a general example, without retrofit. You can implement your data fetch inside my `getTestData` method.

To begin with, in order to understand the basic principles of working with Compose, I suggest you study [compose tutorials](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/tutorial).

Compose uses view models to perform complex data manipulations. I will use the basic version, but you can also check out [Hilt](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/libraries#hilt) for more complex architecture.

In order for changing the state of an object to lead to a recomposition, you can use:

1. The `mutableStateObject` - this is a specially created container for compose that will update the view if the value has changed
2. you can also use `LiveData` and `Flow`, they can both be cast to mutableStateObject.

Note that `mutableStateObject` will not alert you to changes in the container object fields if you pass a complex class there. It will only notify you when the value itself changes, so it is recommended to use it only for simple types.

You can also use `mutableStateListOf` to store collections. In my example you will see both: with `mutableStateListOf` it is convenient to add/delete objects to the collection, while `mutableStateObject` with `List` lying inside is easier to completely replace with new objects.

Inside Composable functions you need to wrap your mutable state objects with `remember` to prevent reinitializing them on each composition, and inside your view model you don't need to do that, because it's not gonna be reinitialized in any case.

`SwipeRefresh` is not part of compose, it's a library made by compose maintainers too. To install it follow [this instructions](https://google.github.io/accompanist/swiperefresh/#download).

I'm using two columns here just to show difference between `mutableStateOf` and `mutableStateListOf`, you can remove `Row` and one of `LazyColumn`

```
class ScreenViewModel : ViewModel() {
    var list by mutableStateOf(emptyList<String>())
    var mutableList = mutableStateListOf<String>()
    var isRefreshing by mutableStateOf(false)

    init {
        refresh()
    }

    fun refresh() {
        isRefreshing = true
        viewModelScope.launch {
            list = getTestData()
            mutableList.addAll(0, list)
            isRefreshing = false
        }
    }

    suspend fun getTestData(): List<String> {
        // emulate network call
        delay(1000)
        return List(100) {
            Random.nextInt(100).toString()
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun TestView() {
    val viewModel: ScreenViewModel = viewModel()
    SwipeRefresh(
        state = rememberSwipeRefreshState(viewModel.isRefreshing),
        onRefresh = {
            viewModel.refresh()
        },
    ) {
        Row {
            LazyColumn(
                modifier = Modifier.weight(1f) // this needed inly for two columns case
            ) {
                itemsIndexed(viewModel.list) { i, item ->
                    Text("$i $item")
                }
            }
            LazyColumn(
                modifier = Modifier.weight(1f) // this needed inly for two columns case
            ) {
                itemsIndexed(viewModel.mutableList) { i, item ->
                    Text("$i $item")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: thanks for your comment sir but I want a more generalised solution using an API call!

Comment: @Ramanjeet why don't you copy your own API call code instead of mine `getTestData`?

Comment: that's what I wanted to know how can I integrate my kotlin code using retrofit APIs into jetpack compose... Shall I use the same code without any modification??

Comment: @Ramanjeet basically yes. I showed your all the UI part of Jetpack Compose, if you know how retrofit works it should be no problem for you to insert it.